Choosing piezoelectric "speakers"
So I'm wanting to restuff the dollar store headphones I have with piezoelectric "speakers" (the round disk things that make noise) for use with my crystal radio. (Essentially creating my own vintage high impedance headphones. Those things are EXPENSIVE!)
But after testing the ones I salvaged, their all different! They have different frequency responses and volumes!
I DO have this piezoelectric buzzer I took from a "talking" smoke detector. That thing works a treat! Sensitive, good volume, good frequency response. Works great as a crystal radio earpiece! Unfortunately there are NO part numbers on it, and even if there where, they probably wouldn't lead to anything.
So, how do I look for and choose the right piezoelectric speakers/transducers/whatever these things are called on something like mouser or digikey? I don't know what things to be looking for (except size).


how do I look for and choose the right piezoelectric
speakers/transducers/whatever these things are called on something
like mouser or digikey?

You look for devices that have a suitable bandwidth for audio. That information (the spectral response) will be shown in the data sheet. Those that don't contain a suitable frequency response graph will likely be unsuitable for anything other than applications like "sounders" or devices that are used for sonar type applications.

yeah, you're left to test the ones not labeled for "articulated audio" applications yourself. They can be surprisingly good (I used an absolute no-name no-labels back-of-our-drawer-you-get-it-for-free one for vibrational diagnostics on human knee joints, but it's been no fun figuring out appropriate operational characteristics)

Ah... BANDWIDTH! That's the term! Thank you.
